# Only submit 'relevant' parts of HTML form

Tags: php, html, forms

Apologies if it's a stupid but it's been a long day.
So my form look something like this...

```
<form action="/basket.php" method="get">
.co.uk
<select name="years">
<option value="1">1 year</option>
<option value="2">2 years</option>
<option value="3">3 years</option>
<option value="4">4 years</option>
<option value="5">5 years</option>
</select>
<input type="checkbox" name="url" value=".co.uk">
<br>
.com
<select name="years">
<option value="1">1 year</option>
<option value="2">2 years</option>
<option value="3">3 years</option>
<option value="4">4 years</option>
<option value="5">5 years</option>
</select>
<input type="checkbox" name="url" value=".com">
<button type="submit">
</form>
```

Let say I only ticked the `.com` parameter and changed the years to 3 years..
I would currently get the URL as follows:

```
/basket.php?years=1&url=.com&years=3
```

What I would like is...

```
/basket.php?url=.com&years=3
```

The actually form contains more choices but I only want to submit the 'lines' that have the final checkbox ticked.

Hope this make sense! Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Then disable the other select elements via JS if the corresponding checkbox is checked.

Comment: How did it go? Did my answer solve your issue? If not, is there something which I can expand on?

Comment: I ended up re-writing the PHP scripts to change the value of each one so they are unique and run inline with each other. This led me to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if your two checkboxes are mutually exclusive, you want to be using radio buttons so that only one can be checked, like so:

```
<input type="radio" name="url" value=".com"/>
<input type="radio" name="url" value=".co.uk"/>
```

Assuming you're looking for a PHP solution rather than one which uses JavaScript, I would suggest having your form `POST` to `basket.php`, which should determine which inputs to keep based on the value of `$_POST['url']`, and then redirect with the corresponding `years` value.

Also note that you should use a different `name` for your `select` elements so that they can be distinguished between.

That being said, the best option would be to use two `form` elements, but this would require either two submit buttons, or JavaScript to perform the submission.

Also, if they both share the same options for `years`, you could remove the duplicate `select` to make things easier.